# How do I replace values in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace

I want to replace elements in a np.array, for instance:

```
arr = np.array([4,5,6,7,3])
```

I want to replace every element which meets my condition with a given value, for example 3<=x<=5. And replace it with a random number such as randint(90, 99).

Therefore, my expected output is:

```
[91 94  6  7 92]
```

I tried something like this:

```
out = np.where(arr>4, randint(90, 99), arr)
```

But I have 2 probelms: 
1) I can't specity an interval
2) I can't get 3 random numbers - but only one

Comment: What was your attempt? This kind of thing is bread and butter of numpy and would be covered in most tutorials

Comment: I'm not really familiar with numpy, but this seems pretty simple. Can you please show what you've tried?

Comment: Second answer solves your problem

Comment: Use this: `arr[np.argwhere((3<=arr)&(arr<=5))] = 99`

Comment: @Vlad how can I assign a randomInt ?
if I try arr[np.argwhere((3<=arr)&(arr<=5))] = randint(90, 99)
it won't assign 3 different integers, but only 1 random..

Comment: You want to assign the same random number for each element that meets condition or each element that meets condition is assigned to number drawn from some distribution?

Comment: @vlad no need for `np.argwhere`. `arr[(3 <= arr) & (arr <= 5)] = 99`. The OP has now decided to change the assigned value to some random number; the question continues to expand even after being closed

Comment: To get your three random values: `arr[(3 <= arr) & (arr <= 5)] = np.random.randint(90, 99, 3)`. Numpy `random` will allow you to specify a `size` to give more than 1 result, which will then be "unpacked" into the places where your filter is True. Of course, this issue can easily expand again when we don't know _how many_ values will be True, but we can't keep expanding a single question to cover these things. That's not how SO works.

Comment: @roganjosh, you're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -4):

Use a loop, it's simple:

```
j=0
for i in arr:
    if(3<=i and i<=5)
        arr[j]=99
        j+=1
```

Comment: I though there was some build-in function for this..

Comment: No, _don't_ use a python loop for this. If you do that, you may as well be using python lists. This defeats the purpose of arrays. The whole point of numpy is being able to vectorize this kind of thing and get orders of magnitude speed up over regular python.

Comment: Neither simple nor appropriate for numpy...

Comment: Just because you will not use _explict_ loops, doesn't mean you will not use it at all.

Comment: No, but I'd rather my loop runs in C code that can also duck under the GIL and runs several hundred times faster.